# d3.js d3.json is not working - how to make this function work?

Tags: d3.js

Trying to develop a data visualization app with d3.js
Using a local json file named "yelp_test_set_business.json"
When I attempt to use d3.json to load this data, nothing is being passed to the callback function, which, in tern, also triggers an error within crossfilter.js library.

here is my entire file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>

    <script src='javascript/d3.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascript/crossfilter.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascript/dc.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascript/jquery-1.12.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        /********************************************************
         *                                                       *
         *   dj.js example using Yelp Kaggle Test Dataset        *
         *   Eol 9th May 2013                        *
         *                                                       *
         ********************************************************/

        /********************************************************
         *                                                       *
         *   Step0: Load data from json file                     *
         *                                                       *
         ********************************************************/
        d3.json("data/yelp_test_set_business.json", function (yelp_data) {

            /********************************************************
             *                                                       *
             *   Step1: Create the dc.js chart objects & ling to div *
             *                                                       *
             ********************************************************/
            var bubbleChart = dc.bubbleChart("#dc-bubble-graph");
            var pieChart = dc.pieChart("#dc-pie-graph");
            var volumeChart = dc.barChart("#dc-volume-chart");
            var lineChart = dc.lineChart("#dc-line-chart");
            var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#dc-table-graph");
            var rowChart = dc.rowChart("#dc-row-graph");

            /********************************************************
             *                                                       *
             *   Step2:  Run data through crossfilter                *
             *                                                       *
             ********************************************************/
            var ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data);

            /********************************************************
             *                                                       *
             *   Step3:  Create Dimension that we'll need            *
             *                                                       *
             ********************************************************/

            // for volumechart
            var cityDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.city; });
            var cityGroup = cityDimension.group();
            var cityDimensionGroup = cityDimension.group().reduce(
                    //add
                    function(p,v){
                        ++p.count;
                        p.review_sum += v.review_count;
                        p.star_sum += v.stars;
                        p.review_avg = p.review_sum / p.count;
                        p.star_avg = p.star_sum / p.count;
                        return p;
                    },
                    //remove
                    function(p,v){
                        --p.count;
                        p.review_sum -= v.review_count;
                        p.star_sum -= v.stars;
                        p.review_avg = p.review_sum / p.count;
                        p.star_avg = p.star_sum / p.count;
                        return p;
                    },
                    //init
                    function(p,v){
                        return {count:0, review_sum: 0, star_sum: 0, review_avg: 0, star_avg: 0};
                    }
            );

            // for pieChart
            var startValue = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                return d.stars*1.0;
            });
            var startValueGroup = startValue.group();

            // For datatable
            var businessDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.business_id; });
            /********************************************************
             *                                                       *
             *   Step4: Create the Visualisations                    *
             *                                                       *
             ********************************************************/

            bubbleChart.width(650)
                    .height(300)
                    .dimension(cityDimension)
                    .group(cityDimensionGroup)
                    .transitionDuration(1500)
                    .colors(["#a60000","#ff0000", "#ff4040","#ff7373","#67e667","#39e639","#00cc00"])
                    .colorDomain([-12000, 12000])

                    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5.5]))
                    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5.5]))
                    .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2500]))
                    .keyAccessor(function (p) {
                        return p.value.star_avg;
                    })
                    .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                        return p.value.review_avg;
                    })
                    .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
                        return p.value.count;
                    })
                    .transitionDuration(1500)
                    .elasticY(true)
                    .yAxisPadding(1)
                    .xAxisPadding(1)
                    .label(function (p) {
                        return p.key;
                    })
                    .renderLabel(true)
                    .renderlet(function (chart) {
                        rowChart.filter(chart.filter());
                    })
                    .on("postRedraw", function (chart) {
                        dc.events.trigger(function () {
                            rowChart.filter(chart.filter());
                        });
                    });
            ;


            pieChart.width(200)
                    .height(200)
                    .transitionDuration(1500)
                    .dimension(startValue)
                    .group(startValueGroup)
                    .radius(90)
                    .minAngleForLabel(0)
                    .label(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
                    .on("filtered", function (chart) {
                        dc.events.trigger(function () {
                            if(chart.filter()) {
                                console.log(chart.filter());
                                volumeChart.filter([chart.filter()-.25,chart.filter()-(-0.25)]);
                            }
                            else volumeChart.filterAll();
                        });
                    });

            volumeChart.width(230)
                    .height(200)
                    .dimension(startValue)
                    .group(startValueGroup)
                    .transitionDuration(1500)
                    .centerBar(true)
                    .gap(17)
                    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 5.5]))
                    .elasticY(true)
                    .on("filtered", function (chart) {
                        dc.events.trigger(function () {
                            if(chart.filter()) {
                                console.log(chart.filter());
                                lineChart.filter(chart.filter());
                            }
                            else
                            {lineChart.filterAll()}
                        });
                    })
                    .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {return v;});

            console.log(startValueGroup.top(1)[0].value);

            lineChart.width(230)
                    .height(200)
                    .dimension(startValue)
                    .group(startValueGroup)
                    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 5.5]))
                    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
                        return d.value;
                    })
                    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                    .elasticY(true)
                    .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {return v;});   ;

            rowChart.width(340)
                    .height(850)
                    .dimension(cityDimension)
                    .group(cityGroup)
                    .renderLabel(true)
                    .colors(["#a60000","#ff0000", "#ff4040","#ff7373","#67e667","#39e639","#00cc00"])
                    .colorDomain([0, 0])
                    .renderlet(function (chart) {
                        bubbleChart.filter(chart.filter());
                    })
                    .on("filtered", function (chart) {
                        dc.events.trigger(function () {
                            bubbleChart.filter(chart.filter());
                        });
                    });


            dataTable.width(800).height(800)
                    .dimension(businessDimension)
                    .group(function(d) { return "List of all Selected Businesses"
                    })
                    .size(100)
                    .columns([
                        function(d) { return d.name; },
                        function(d) { return d.city; },
                        function(d) { return d.stars; },
                        function(d) { return d.review_count; },
                        function(d) { return '<a href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:' + d.latitude + '+' + d.longitude +"\" target=\"_blank\">Map</a>"}
                    ])
                    .sortBy(function(d){ return d.stars; })
                    // (optional) sort order, :default ascending
                    .order(d3.ascending);
            /********************************************************
             *                                                       *
             *   Step6:  Render the Charts                           *
             *                                                       *
             ********************************************************/

            dc.renderAll();
        });
    </script>

    <link href='stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--<link href='stylesheets/dc.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->

    <!--<script src='simple_vis.js' type='text/javascript'></script>-->
</head>

<body>
<div class='container' id='main-container'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='container' style='font: 10px sans-serif;'>
            <h3>Visualisation of <a href="http://www.kaggle.com/c/yelp-recruiting">Kaggle Yelp Test Business Data</a> set (using <a href="http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/">dc.js</a>)</h3>
            <h4>Demo for the <a href="http://www.meetup.com/Dublin-Data-Visualisation/">Dublin Data Visualisation Meetup Group</a></h4>
            <div class='row-fluid'>
                <div class='remaining-graphs span8'>
                    <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <div class='bubble-graph span12' id='dc-bubble-graph'>
                            <h4>Average Rating (x-axis), Average Number of Reviews (y-axis), Number of Business' (Size)</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <div class='pie-graph span4' id='dc-pie-graph'>
                            <h4>Average Rating in Stars (Pie)</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class='pie-graph span4' id='dc-volume-chart'>
                            <h4>Average Rating in Stars / Number of Reviews (Bar)</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class='pie-graph span4' id='dc-line-chart'>
                            <h4>Average Rating in Stars / Number of Reviews (Line)</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /other little graphs go here -->
                    <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <div class='span12 table-graph'>
                            <h4>Data Table for Filtered Businesses</h4>
                            <table class='table table-hover dc-data-table' id='dc-table-graph'>
                                <thead>
                                <tr class='header'>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>City</th>
                                    <th>Review Score (in Stars)</th>
                                    <th>Total Reviews</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='remaining-graphs span4'>
                    <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <div class='row-graph span12' id='dc-row-graph' style='color:black;'>
                            <h4>Reviews Per City</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following call:

```
d3.json("data/yelp_test_set_business.json", function (yelp_data) { ...}
```

returns nothing in yelp_data

Does anyone know why this is hapenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing like this to load your JSON:

```
 d3.json("data/yelp_test_set_business.json", function (yelp_data) {
```

It should have been:

```
 d3.json("data/yelp_test_set_business.json", function (error, yelp_data) {
```

Read [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, this error is related to the fact that you just open the `html` file in your browser, which then tries to open the `json` file using the `file:///` protocol, resulting in a cross origin violation.

D3 doc on [requests](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests).

One way to fix it is just by using a web server to serve the `.html` and the `.json`.

If you have `python` installed, just go to the folder where you file is located and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, then navigate with your browser to `http://localhost:8080`. This way both the `.html` and `.json` will be served from the same origin (namely `localhost:8080`), and you will be able to load file via `d3.json`, `d3.csv`, etc...